# Detect iBeacon with different major and minor values

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ibeacon

I am trying a simple test right now.

**Device 1:**

Acts as beacon with UUID: XXX-XXX-XXX 
Major: 1000
Minor: 1234

```
self.peripheralData = [MyRegion peripheralDataWithMeasuredPower:nil];
[self.peripheralManager startAdvertising:self.peripheralData];
```

**Device 2:**

Acts as listener for region with UUID: XXX-XXX-XXX

```
locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:_region
```

Device 2 does not detect Device 1.  It only detects Device 1 if I program to listen to the region to have major:1000 and minor: 1234.

**Does this sound right?**

Let's say i have 100 phones acting as beacon with same uuid and identifier but different major and minor values. And I have 50 phones acting as listeners for the specific uuid and idenfitifer... Can I find all beacons with that uuid and read their major and minor values?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you post the code that creates the regions on both devices?

Comment: Sure. It's just created using initwithuuid major and minor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you initialize your region, use

```
region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid identifier:identifierString];
```

instead of something like

```
region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid major:[major integerValue] minor:[minor integerValue] identifier:identifierString];
```

By not specifying the major and minor values, all beacons with the matching UUID should be detected.  It works for me.

Comment: If I dont specify the major and minor, how will i be able to ready them? :-/

Comment: You can specify major and minor when you create the beacon, but for the device that is detecting the beacons, the region created to monitor will only be as specific as you make it.  i.e. if you specify uuid, major and minor it will look for that one beacon. if you specify just uuid and major, it will look for beacons that match those.  And specifying only UUID will detect ALL beacons with that UUID.

Comment: Ok it works for me. My mistake was that i was reusing the regions instead of creating new ones.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key to your problem lies in this comment:

> Sure. It's just created using initwithuuid major and minor –  Legolas
>   yesterday

There are 3 different calls to create a beacon region:

```
initWithProximityUUID:identifier:
```

,

```
initWithProximityUUID:major:identifier:
```

and

```
initWithProximityUUID:major:minor:identifier:
```

If you want to detect beacons with any UUID, you need to use the first form that does not specify the major or minor value.

Then you need to also call startRangingBeaconsInRegion: and look at the beacon objects that are returned in the ranging calls.

DidEnterRegion calls only include major or minor values if they are part of the region.

The ranging callbacks include all the beacons that are detected, including their major and minor values, distance and proximity, etc.

Comment: That's correct. If you need a region with a different UUID, major, or minor, you need to create a new one. The UUID, major, and minor values are all readonly properties of beacon regions.

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate a problem in your code, try doing the exact same thing with my free [Locate for iBeacon](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ibeacon-locate/id738709014) app in the app store.  Try making one or both sides of the transmitter/detector be this app vs. your custom app.

If it does not work with Locate for iBeacon on both sides, then something is wrong with one of your devices.  If it does work with Locate for iBeacon on one side, please post your code for the side that is having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Which delegate methods are you using for the Location Manager? Sometimes DidEnter is not called if you're already in the region i.e. you turn on the transmitting beacon before starting the one that's doing the monitoring. If that's the case monitor for state changes instead and you should be good.

Also, I highly recommend using David's Locate iBeacon app. It will really speed up your development process. Thanks D!